# how to prevent back button to last page after user logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a log in page where user enters username and password and then the user is redirected to his account page, but when i press the back button it takes me back to the log in page. How do i prevent that from happening.

Comment: when visiting the login page, just check if the user isn't logged in already. if so, redirect to an other page. It's easier to solve this with it then fiddling with the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Devise, Check in Your controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Normally the back action on an already logged in user don't put him back to the form.

Comment: thanks for your response even he press back button on the browser same doesn't work so please help me

Answer (score 0):

`authenticate_user!` is a devise methods. If your are not using devise then you can create a attach a `before_filter` to your login action and redirects user if users is signed_in.

Answer (score 0):

I use a a simple signed_in? method in the new action which renders my sign in page, it looks roughly like this:

```
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    def signed_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

when your user hits the back button it does not re-run the server code to render the login page, it just shows the cached browser version, so you could try and tell the browser to not cache the login page and then add the addition of the server side check (as others have shown)

add this to your ApplicationController

```
def no_browser_cache
  response.headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate
  # response.headers["Expires"] = 0 -> this line kills heroku deployments
  # HTTP 1.0
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  # HTTP 1.1 'pre-check=0, post-check=0' (IE specific)
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, pre-check=0, post-check=0'
end
```

then put a before_filter in your login controller that executes that method

then add in your 'already logged in' server side check